# Изменение цвета svg изображения по маске, загруженного в HTML с помощью <img>

Tags: css, html5, svg, svg-animation, clip-path

Пытаюсь обтравить прямоугольник по маске SVG. проблема в том, что **высота прямоугольника динамическая** (от 0px до 32px), а **SVG-изображение подгружается из файла** (фигуры могут быть совершенно разные, загруженные пользователем, и нет возможности жёстко подгружать их код).

Пробовал применять `use` внутри svg совместно с `clipPath` (да и с `overflow` тоже, и с вариациями) - не получается, да и вообще по ходу use работает только для спрайтов (?):

```
<svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="/storage/uploads/default.svg"></use>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
        <rect style="position:relative;z-index:5;" width="32" fill="#78DE16" height="10"></rect>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Пробовал вставлять svg как CSS фон и вешать overflow: hidden (и также ещё с clipPath) - безрезультатно.

[image: Что есть]

```
<svg class="icon" style="background-image: url(/storage/uploads/default.svg);width: 32px;height: 32px;position: relative;overflow: hidden;">
        <rect style="position:relative;z-index:5;" width="32" fill="#78DE16" height="10"></rect>
</svg>
```

Примерно то, что должно получиться (прямоугольник не обязательно снизу, но если есть возможность...):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать такое?

Comment: use - это если по русскому то это клонирование

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Добавление изображений из внешнего источника

> картинка может быть совершенно разной, и каждый рас статически её
>   прописывать не получится. Например, такой: i.imgur.com/B7tqOMS.png

Самый простой способ добавить файл из внешнего источника с помощью тега `<img>`
Но это будет как отдельный объект и стилизация, маски в этом случае не работают. 
Но можно применить фильтры, как в первом ответе и тогда можно перекрашивать изображения в любой цвет полностью или частично.

- Я загрузил вашу картинку на сервер.
- Добавляю её в приложение с помощью `<img>`
- Закрашиваю её с помощью фильтров.

*Этот прием интересен ещё тем, что можно стилизовать SVG в формате `base64`, стилизация которого не доступна обычными способами.*

```css
img {
filter:url(#filter1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Face.svg" width="371" height="348" >

<svg  version="1.1" width="371" height="348" viewBox="0 0 371 348" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
 <filter id="filter1" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#35B62E" />
      <feOffset  dy="150">
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
   </defs>
 
</svg>
```

**Пример изменения цвета при наведении курсора.**

Использованы разные значения атрибута фильтра - `dy=150` и `dy="65"` для достижения  разной высоты заливки цветом.

```css
img {
filter:url(#filter_G);
}

img:hover {
filter:url(#filter_R);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Face.svg" width="371" height="348" >

<svg  version="1.1" width="371" height="348" viewBox="0 0 371 348" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
 <filter id="filter_G" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#35B62E" />
      <feOffset  dy="150">
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter> 
 
  <filter id="filter_R" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="red" />
      <feOffset  dy="65">
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter> 
   </defs>
 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Как можно сделать такое?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это то, что вы хотите получить на выходе, то можно не загружать извне файлы SVG c цветными прямоугольниками, не связываться  масками, `clip-path`, с командой `use`, с которой надо будет ещё решать проблемы со стилизацией. А это не просто.

*Всё можно сделать проще:*

**Есть более универсальный способ, как закрасить часть фигуры в любой цвет.**

Можно воспользоваться фильтрами SVG

`<feFlood flood-color="#35B62E" />
      <feOffset  dy="20">
      </feOffset>`

Первый фильтр обеспечивает закраску в нужный цвет.
Второй фильтр посредством атрибута  `dy="20"` устанавливает отступ от начала закраски

```html
<svg  version="1.1" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
 <filter id="filter1" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#35B62E" />
      <feOffset  dy="20">
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
   </defs>
  <path  fill="black" d="m32 6 19 11-0.02 22-19 11-19-11 0.02-22z"  filter= "url(#filter1)" />
  
</svg>
```

Таким способом можно закрасить любую фигуру например окружность, но в этот раз отступ сделаем по оси `X`

```html
<svg  version="1.1" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
 <filter id="filter1" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#35B62E" />
      <feOffset  dx="16">
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
   </defs>
  <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="16" fill="black" filter="url(#filter1)" />
  
</svg>
```

### Анимация закраски

Также довольно просто, при необходимости, можно  сделать анимацию закраски.

Для этого надо будет анимировать атрибуты `dx` или `dy`, которые отвечают за отступ от начала закраски.

*В примере ниже закраска начинается при наведении курсора и обратно при уходе курсора*

```html
<svg  version="1.1" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
 <filter id="filter1" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#35B62E" />
      <feOffset dy="0">
        <animate id="anim" attributeName="dy" values="0;20" dur="1s" begin="path1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>  
    <animate id="anim" attributeName="dy" values="20;0" dur="1s" begin="path1.mouseout" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>  
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  
 </defs>
  <path id="path1"  fill="black" d="m32 6 19 11-0.02 22-19 11-19-11 0.02-22z"  filter= "url(#filter1)" stroke-width="1"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Это то, что мне нужно только для варианта по умолчанию. Но ещё раз, картинка может быть совершенно разной, и каждый рас статически её прописывать не получится. Например, такой: https://i.imgur.com/B7tqOMS.png